# Save formulas and conditions on a Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have the following SQL tables:

```
create table dbo.Basket ( 
  Id int not null
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
)

create table dbo.Product ( 
  Id int not null
  Name nvarchar (80) not null,
  Price decimal not null
)

create table dbo.BasketProduct ( 
  BasketId int not null,
  ProductId int not null,
)
```

I have different ways to create a Basket. For example:

1. With N products with Total Price in range 200 USD to 240 USD;
2. With 8 products being the cheapest 5 USD and the most expensive 40 USD;
3. ...

On my application code I determine which way I will build that basked.

But I would like to save the rules applied so I can know how each basket was build in the future.

I seed different options:

1. Save the SQL produced by the algorithm on a table.
   The problem with this is that I need to know the specific values of each parameter used.
2. Save the conditions on a table. For example:

   -TotalProducts=8
   -CheapestProductPrice=5
   -MostExpensiveProductPrice=40
   -ProductCategories=Book,CD

   In this case I am not sure if there is a normalized way to save conditions on a database.

   One condition that seems strange is one where there is an enumeration. 
   For example: `ProductCategories=Book,CD`
3. Maybe have a table with formulas and then for each Basket have a FK to the formula used and the values for its parameters?

Could someone advice me on this?

Comment: It largely depends on how many different rules you have, whether you can enumerate these rules and what you intend to do later with this information. In the simplest form it is your third option - a table with the list of all possible rules and ID for each rule, then store this RuleID in your main table.

Comment: The rules are used to filter products to the create a basket. So when I create a basket I need to know which rules where used so in case I want to create a similar basket I can do it ... Does it make sense?